# prove that a set forms a basis for other set

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that $ S:=\{1 + x, x − x^2,2 + 3x^2\}$ forms a basis for $P_2 =\{a+bx+cx^2:a,b,c\inℝ\}$.

Showing that the $P_2=\text{span(S)}$ is trivial.
While showing that the elements of S are linearly independent is a bit tricky technically $\exists,c_1,c_2,c_3$ s.t 
$$c_1*(1+x)+c_2(x-x^2)+c_3(2+3x^2)\neq0$$ 
One possible solution I think of is bringing it to quadratic equation form and showing that the discriminant<0 i.e. above statement is true. However, it also does not give the desired result. Is there better solution? Also, I don't notice that any of those elements are linear combinations of the other two.
Need some hints

Comment: You meant at the end of your first line the set of polynomials of degree less than or equal $\;2\;$ ...right?

Comment: @DonAntonio Sorry No

Comment: Then that set is **not** a linear space...

Comment: @DonAntonio I guess the set $P_2$ shold be as described above just made an edit

Comment: @DonAntonio hang on what if we define ${P_2}$ as you said polynomials of degree not exceeding 2 , what'd happen?

Comment: That's **exactly** what you defined...:) . It **must** be that way, as otherwise that'd be not closed under addition. Now it's fine.

Comment: @ErikHambardzumyan Then the question would be fine.

Comment: @DonAntonio nice :) so any hints?

Comment: @ErikHambardzumyan You may see my answer. In particular, since you are working with polynomials, so elimination is also allowed. This is in particular useful if you are working with linear combinations of many polynomials, so that you can use values for $x$ to eliminate coefficients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$c_1(1+x)+c_2(x-x^2)+c_3(2+3x^2)=0\iff (3c_3-c_2)x^2+(c_2+c_1)x+(2c_3+c_1)=0$$

But we know that a polynomial is the *zero* polynomial iff all its coefficients are zero, so we get:

$$\begin{cases}3c_3-c_2=0\\c_2+c_1=0\\2c_3+c_1=0\end{cases}$$

Prove now that the above three equalities **force** $\;c_1=c_2=c_3=0\;$ and thus the given set of vectors is linearly independent and thus a basis of $\;\Bbb P_2\;$

Comment: Oh right got stuck on basic stuff

Answer (score 2):

You want to prove that
$$c_1(1+x)+c_2(x-x^2)+c_3(2+3x^2)=0 \ \Rightarrow \ c_1=c_2=c_3=0$$
If you expand, you get
$$(3c_3-c_2)x^2+(c_1+c_2)x+(c_1+2c_3)=0$$
and taking into account that a polynomial is $0$ if, and only if, its coefficients are $0$, you end up with the system of equations
$$\begin{cases} 3c_3-c_2=0 \\ c_1+c_2=0 \\ c_1+2c_3=0\end{cases}$$
Now, you want to prove that the previous system has only the trivial solution (that is, $c_1=c_2=c_3=0$). That can be done by checking that the determinant of the coefficient matrix is not zero:
$$\left|\begin{matrix} 0 & -1 & 3 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \\1 & 0 & 2 \end{matrix}\right|=3\neq 0$$

Comment: You are missing a $\;3\;$ as the coefficient of $\;x^2\;$ in the third vector...

Answer (score 0):

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & -x^2 & 3x^2 \\
    x & x & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 2 \\
    \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
    c_1  \\
    c_2  \\
    c_3  \\
    \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
    0  \\
    0  \\
    0  \\
    \end{bmatrix}$$

is the matrix representation of the system of equations we need to have. Here, if we define $A = \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & -x^2 & 3x^2 \\
    x & x & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 2 \\
    \end{bmatrix}, c = \begin{bmatrix}
    c_1  \\
    c_2  \\
    c_3  \\
    \end{bmatrix}$ if $\det(A) = 0$ for **all** $x$, then we have a non-zero solution for vector $c$ hence the set $S$ is linearly dependent. However, we can find out that $\det(A) = x^2 = 0$ iff $x = 0$, which implies that $c = 0$ and $S$ is a linearly independent set.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement about 'linearly independent', that "there exist $c_1$, $c_2$, $c_3$ such that $c_1(1+ x)+ c_2(x- x^2)+ c_3(2+ 3x^2)\ne 0$" is incorrect.  "Linearly independent" means that the **only** $c_1, c_2, c_3$ such that $c_1(1+ x)+ c_2(x- x^2)+ c_3(2+ 3x^2)= 0$ (for all x) are $c_1= c_2= c_3= 0$.  To prove that, do the multiplication to get $c_1+ c_2x+ c_2x- c_2x^2+ 2c_3+ 3c_3x^2= (c_1+ 3c_3)+ c_2x+ (3c_3- c_2)x^2= 0$.  Taking x= 0 that becomes $c_1+ 3c_3= 0$.  Taking x= 1, $c2+ 3c_3- c_2= 3c_3= 0$ and taking x= -1, $-c_2+ 3c_3- c_2= 3c_3- 2c_2= 0$.  From the second equation, $c_3= 0$ and then the first and second equations become $c_1= 0$ and $-c_2= 0$ so that $c_2= 0$.